# Android Watch Face Development

Tags: android, wear-os, watch, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.1

Here is gives me info:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html
(Implement Service and Callback Methods)

Where should this class be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Wear watch faces need to be included within a [Wearable app](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) which is a separate apk that runs directly on the Android Wear device.

Comment: so a watch face within the app is not gonna be interfering with the watch face's purity? thanks a lot...